# Ошибка при компиляции CodeDom

Tags: c#, компилятор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка при компиляции приложения через CodeDom

Comment: Покажите исходник, который компилируете. Небось забыли добавить System.Linq?

Comment: System.Linq был, добавил System.Xml.Linq - все заработало, спасибо :)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решается добавлением

```
CompilerParameters name = new CompilerParameters();
            name.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.Linq.dll");
```